# import snowboydetect generates errors

Tags: python-3.x, snowboy

I've successfully installed snowboy but when I try to import snowboydetect an error just pops out.

Traceback (most recent call last): File "demo.py", line 1, in import snowboydecoder File "/home/pi/Downloads/rpi-arm-raspbian-8.0-1.1.1/snowboydecoder.py", line 5, in import snowboydetect File "/home/pi/Downloads/rpi-arm-raspbian-8.0-1.1.1/snowboydetect.py", line 28, in _snowboydetect = swig_import_helper() File "/home/pi/Downloads/rpi-arm-raspbian-8.0-1.1.1/snowboydetect.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper _mod = imp.load_module('_snowboydetect', fp, pathname, description) File "/home/pi/venv/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module return load_dynamic(name, filename, file) File "/home/pi/venv/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic return _load(spec) ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__snowboydetect)

Comment: The issue is reported in this github tracker: https://github.com/Kitt-AI/snowboy/issues/271. have a look.

Answer (score 1):

As per their github page, you need to add some modules as prerequisite to snowboy. Check it out here: https://github.com/wanleg/snowboyPi

Comment: I've installed all th requirements. @therochvoices